# WSO2 ESB Proxy set JMS reply to Queue

Tags: proxy, jms, wso2, wso2-esb

Does anybody know how to set the JMS reply to queue in a proxy service so that the receiving service will respond to a different proxy. I have tried pretty much everything you can imagine based on scouring the net and nothing seems to work.

As I understand it, from what I have found on synapse forums, I should be able to set an Axis2 level property called JMS_REPLY_TO to anything I want and it should work but it doesn't.

Any assistance would be really appreciated. I am in a dire situation now with the project I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [1] additional JMS parameters that you require to accomplish this.
There you can find parameters as follows which can be append to the jms endpoint url where you want to have a response queue.

i.e

transport.jms.ReplyDestinationType - Reply destination type (queue or topic)
transport.jms.ReplyDestination - JNDI name of the reply destination

[1] - http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.2/docs/transports/transports-catalog.html#JmsTrp